# Difficulty writing regex pattern

Tags: java, regex, split, tokenize

i want to tokenize a .txt file which is as follows
products,brands
tv,names:lg:sony
fridge,kelvinator,names:godrej

i want to omit the first line`products,brands`

and put data from the next line onwards in an object of a class which has this structure
    class Product{
    String title;
    list brands;
    }

title should contain anything before the first word before ","
list brands should contain all seperate tokens after "names:"
i have to ignore the word "names" and not put in object fields

example an object named prod should contain this data
prod.title=tv
list of brands must contain lg and sony

what is the best method of doing it??

this is the code::

```
public class tokenize {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=0;
    try {
        FileReader fr=new FileReader("myfiles\\"+"sample.txt");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;
        try {
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                String tokens[]=line.split(", | :");
                while(tokens.length!=0)
                {
                    System.out.println(tokens[i]);
                    i++;
                    System.out.println();
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: The best way to do it is to try coding and ask here for specific problems. You perfectly described what has to be done and how classes should work, so code it and come back here with specific questions if you have some

Comment: Can you show the code you already tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would use a `Scanner` object to read line by line
2. And insert the `Pattern` needed through Scanner

Comment: FileReader fr=new FileReader("myfiles\\"+"sample.txt");
   Scanner scn=new Scanner(fr);
   Pattern ptrn=Pattern.compile("\\s*[,:]\\s*");
   scn.useDelimiter(ptrn);
   while(scn.hasNext())
   {
   System.out.println(scn.nextLine());
   }

Comment: this is what i added...it printed the text file as it is

Comment: try `scn.next()` in println()

Comment: also can you give an exact line from the file being used? or is this it?`products,brands tv,names:lg:sony fridge,kelvinator,names:godrej`

Comment: scn.next() worked thanks a lot :)

Comment: but i would also like to know what is wrong in the split i have written
String tokens[]=line.split("\\s*[,:]\\s*");
 it is giving an arrayindexoutofboundexception

Comment: Well, its because of `while(tokens.length!=0)` ..to keep it simple i would write ...
`i=0; 
while(i<tokens.length)
{ 
System.out.println(tokens[i++]);                    
}`
In your code `tokens.length` never decrements(and it shouldn't) thus you get an infinite loop and when your `i` value is `==tokens.length` you get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`...Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Method `split()` receives regular expression where spaces are important.

Change your the split to:

```
String tokens[]=line.split("\\s*[,:]\\s*");
```

This should work. The square brackets mean "any of characters mentioned inside." `\\s*` mean "zero or more whitespaces."

It seems that this is what you need.

Comment: after doing this i am getting an
arrayindexoutofbounds exception...and only products and brands were the two words printed